# Terraform Load balancer error: error retrieving ALB and error reading ELBv2 Target Group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Using hashicorp/aws v3.75.2. terraforma validate was fine. Executing terraform plan I get the following errors:

```
Error: error retrieving ALB (arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:927589092144:loadbalancer/app/globo-web-alb/e138ebc8e894ac7b): ValidationError: 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:927589092144:loadbalancer/app/globo-web-alb/e138ebc8e894ac7b' is not a valid load balancer ARN
│       status code: 400, request id: cb42dcc0-a0a6-42bf-8206-670162edf3ce
│
│   with aws_lb.nginx,
│   on loadbalancer.tf line 5, in resource "aws_lb" "nginx":
│    5: resource "aws_lb" "nginx" {
```

I have the load balancer config in loadbalancer.tf, not sure if other tf files are relevant in this issue.
The tf file is:

```
## aws_elb_service_account
data "aws_elb_service_account" "root" {}

## aws_lb
resource "aws_lb" "nginx" {
  name               = "globo-web-alb"
  internal           = false
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.alb_sg.id]
  subnets            = [aws_subnet.subnet1.id, aws_subnet.subnet2.id]

  enable_deletion_protection = false

  access_logs {
    bucket  = aws_s3_bucket.web_bucket.bucket
    prefix  = "alb-logs"
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nginx" {
  name     = "nginx-alb-tg"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "nginx" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.nginx.arn
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nginx1" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.nginx1.id
  port             = 80
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "nginx2" {
  target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.nginx.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.nginx2.id
  port             = 80
}
```

I am new to Terraform, I am following Pluralsight course: Getting started with Terraform. In the demo they use v3.62 of Terraform.

Comment: Try with newest version of aws provider. This is known, long-lasting [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4552).

Comment: Thanks, still getting the same error. Below the first error I also get: is not a valid target group ARN

Comment: Ask on github. I linked the issue where you can discuss the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I have and waiting for response. One thing I didn't mention is that I was previously using a different AWS account before creating load balancer resources. Then after creating the load balancer resources, I declared new environment variables eg. $env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="efufhuie37h" and $env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="PbFjV8" for a new AWS account before doing terraform init, plan and  apply. Would this be an issue?

Comment: I did destroy all resources with old AWS account before attempting to use terraform apply with new credentials